# Separate resultset from hashtable into 3 tables 

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures, cursor

I am using `SQL Server 2008` and have a `hashtable` which contains data about postcode and its related data. If I take the count of records `groupby` postcode its like this

```
5000 HA
6000 NW
4000 S2
```

I would like to know is there any way of devidng the data into three separate tables.
if we running the first set of records which is `HA`
which will look like

```
Table1               Table2                   Table3
1st record of HA     2nd record of HA       3rd record of HA
4th record of HA     ....etc
```

is it possible to achieve using cursor or any suggestion?

Any help will be appreciate

Thank you

Comment: It seems like what you may be trying to accomplish here is a sort of data balancing.  If this is the case, I don't think this is the right approach, by creating different tables.  You should use something like `NTILE` for this in a single table.

Comment: How do you define who is the 1st or 2nd record?, on what criteria do you want to order the results?. Also, you always want to divide the results on 3 tables?, or thats only cause there are 3 groups on postcode?

Comment: @Lamak: There is no specefic condtion to define 1st or 2nd. Just need to devide data in to three separate table (there about more than 5000 records)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine any possible reason why I would do such a thing. Dividing up into 3 tables will make the data much harder to query later. But if you're stuck with it then I would do something along the lines of this:

BUild a mapping table with three columns A, B, C. Populate the table withthe values you want to go in each table. Shoulf look simliar to this, but woudl go out the the max value you will need.

```
A   B   C
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
10  11  12
```

Create a  temp table using row_number over (don't forget to order by) to so that you can now tell which record is the first HA and which is the second etc.  Now do 3 inserts joining on the number you generated to each column inteh mapping table. If they join to column A insert to tableA, Column B, insert totable B, colmn c insert to table c.